# How to calculate sum of product of first $n$ natural numbers taken three at a time$?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

How to calculate sum of product of $n$ natural numbers taken three at a time$?$

There is a post on stackexchange but in that post it was assumed that the original poster knew how to solve double or triple summation. Moreover it was for $k$ taken at a time.

In my opinion, we  can write the expression of our answer as $$\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\sum_{j = 1}^{n - i}\sum_{h = 1}^{n - j - i} i\cdot(i+j)\cdot(i + j +h)$$ but how to solve it$?$

Is there any general way of doing so$?$

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**What I want to say is this**

Suppose we take first $5$ natural numbers and then we take any three natural numbers lying in between $1$ and $5$ and multiply them (both $1$ and $5$ included). Then there will be $\binom{5}{3}$ ways of doing this. And we also add the product of each way. Then how will we calculate it$?$
$$ $$

> We obtain for $k=3$
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=0}^{n}&\sum_{j=0}^{n-i}\sum_{k=0}^{n-i-j}i(i+j)(i+j+k)\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n-i}\sum_{k=0}^{n-i-j}(i^3+2i^2j+i^2k+ij^2+ijk)\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n-i}\sum_{k=0}^{n-i-j}(i^3+4i^2j+ijk)\tag{7}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^{n}i^3\sum_{j=0}^{n-i}1\sum_{k=0}^{n-i-j}1
> +4\sum_{i=0}^{n}i^2\sum_{j=0}^{n-i}j\sum_{k=0}^{n-i-j}1\tag{8}\\
> &\qquad+\sum_{i=0}^{n}i\sum_{j=0}^{n-i}j\sum_{k=0}^{n-i-j}k\\
> \end{align*}

This person is first distributing the summation over variables and then solving$?$ im having problem here. How to do it? Is there any general way$?#

Comment: Certainly you have tested this for $n=1,2,3$. What did you obtain?

Comment: It's giving correct results...but how to compute the summation @DietrichBurde

Comment: Which results? Which number is the product for small $n$? Please include the results and explain how "taken three at a time" works (it is not clear). For example, for $n=1$, the product of $n=1$ natural numbers taken three at a time gives *what*?

Comment: And could you link the "post on stackexchange" you are referring to (into your post)?

Comment: @DietrichBurde https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1586377/calculate-the-sum-of-first-n-natural-numbers-taken-k-at-a-time

Comment: Very good, then you have your answer there!

Comment: How to solve triple summation @DietrichBurde

Comment: Like in the answers there? They solved it!

Comment: @DietrichBurde how to solve double summation$?$ i know that we can do it by first calculating the inner summation and then the outer one...but the answer there some what distributed it over the variables....I'm having problem there

Comment: I am not understanding the scope of your question.  If you are asking how *this specific* sum is solved, as said already the linked post already goes into considerable detail on that.  If you are asking for clarification on specific steps in the linked solution, then point out specific steps you want to ask about.  If you are asking for general advice on solving triple-summations, or what triple-summations are in the first place... they are just summations inside of other summations.  If you are asking for general advice on single-summations... recall they are linear.

Comment: So, for the step going from $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-i}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-i-j}(i^3+4i^2j+ijk)$ (*labeled as line 7 in the linked post*) to the next line... we split the summation into three parts... recalling that $\sum (a + b) = (\sum a)+(\sum b)$.  Then we factor any variables we can outside of their respective summations so long as they are not the index for that particular summation... recalling that $\sum_i a\cdot f(i) = a\sum_i f(i)$... remembering as well that if we factor everything out, a $1$ can still remain.  Do this for each, and evaluate what remains.

Comment: What remains will be made up of expressions of a standard well known form... $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n 1$ for instance is equal to $n+1$, or $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n i$ is equal to $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and so on...  If your question is about *these*... well then... you need to not be worrying about the problem in your post yet and focusing on the basics.

Comment: @JMoravitz now i understood how he is distributing it... he is simply taking the variables to their respective summations ...like $i$ to the summation with index $i$ and so on....thanks

Answer (score 1):

Surprised that no one gave you a complete answer.  Your posting clearly showed work.

Your method of indexing seems unnatural to me.  Of the $~\displaystyle \binom{n}{3}~$ pertinent **unordered** triples, I will assume that $i > j > k$.  So, you have ordered triples of the form $(i,j,k).$

This means that :

- $i$ can run from $3$ through $n$, inclusive.
- For any value of $i$, you have that $j$ can run from $2$ through $(i-1)$ inclusive.
- For any value of $j$, you have that $k$ can run from $1$ through $(j-1)$ inclusive.

**Tools**:

- $~\displaystyle \sum_{r=1}^s r = \frac{s^2}{2} + \frac{s}{2} ~: ~s \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$
- $~\displaystyle \sum_{r=1}^s r^2 = \frac{s^3}{3} + \frac{s^2}{2} + \frac{s}{6} ~: ~s \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$
- $~\displaystyle \sum_{r=1}^s r^3 = \frac{s^4}{4} + \frac{s^3}{2} + \frac{s^2}{4} ~: ~s \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$
- $~\displaystyle \sum_{r=1}^s r^4 = \frac{s^5}{5} + \frac{s^4}{2} + \frac{s^3}{3} - \frac{s}{30}~: ~s \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$
- $~\displaystyle \sum_{r=1}^s r^5 = \frac{s^6}{6} + \frac{s^5}{2} + \frac{5s^4}{12} - \frac{s^2}{12}~: ~s \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$

For what it's worth, the above formulas may be derived using nothing more than Algebra, Mathematical Induction, and a basic knowledge of Pascal's Triangle.  This means that the derivation can avoid Bernoulli Numbers, Calculus, or Faulhaber's formula.

See, for example, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2697950/general-form-for-sum-of-powers/2698204#2698204).

---

Let $f(i,j)$ denote the sum of the products of the pertinent ordered triples, where $i > j$, and where $k$ runs from $1$ through $(j-1).$

That is, $~\displaystyle f(i,j) = \sum_{k=1}^{j-1} i \times j \times k  ~: i \in \{3,4,\cdots,n\}, ~j \in \{2,3,\cdots,i-1\}.$

Let $g(i)$ denote $~\displaystyle \sum_{j=2}^{i-1} f(i,j).$

Let $H$ denote $~\displaystyle \sum_{i=3}^n g(i).$

Then, the goal is to calculate $H$.

---

For $i,j$ **fixed**,

$$f(i,j) = [i \times j] \times \sum_{k=1}^{j-1} k$$

$$= [i \times j] \times \frac{(j-1)^2}{2} + \frac{j-1}{2}$$

$$= [i \times j] \times \frac{1}{2} \times \left[ ~\left(j^2 - 2j + 1 ~\right) + (j - 1) ~\right]$$

$$= [i \times j] \times \frac{1}{2} \times \left[ ~j^2 - j ~\right]$$

$$\frac{i}{2} \times \left( ~j^3 - j^2 ~\right).$$

---

For $i$ **fixed**:

$$g(i) = \sum_{j=2}^{i-1} f(i,j) = \sum_{j=2}^{i-1} \left[ ~\frac{i}{2} \times \left( ~j^3 - j^2 ~\right) ~\right].$$

There is a mild shortcut here.  Note that when $j=1$, the expression $(j^3 - j^2) = 0.$

Therefore,

$$g(i) = \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} \left[ ~\frac{i}{2} \times \left( ~j^3 - j^2 ~\right) ~\right]$$

$$ = \frac{i}{2} \times \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} ~j^3 \\ 
- \frac{i}{2} \times \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} ~j^2$$

$$= \frac{i}{2} \times ~\left[ ~\frac{(i-1)^4}{4} + \frac{(i-1)^3}{2} + \frac{(i-1)^2}{4} ~\right] \\ 
- \frac{i}{2} ~\left[ ~\frac{(i-1)^3}{3} + \frac{(i-1)^2}{2} + \frac{(i-1)}{6} ~\right]$$

$$= \frac{i}{2} \times ~\left[ ~\frac{(i-1)^4}{4} + \frac{(i-1)^3}{6} - \frac{(i-1)^2}{4} - \frac{i-1}{6} ~\right] $$

$$= \frac{i}{2} \times \frac{1}{12} \times \\
\left\{ \\ 
~~[3i^4 - 12i^3 + 18i^2 - 12i + 3] \\
+ [ 2i^3 - 6i^2 + 6i -2] \\
- [3i^2 - 6i + 3] \\
- [2i - 2] \\
~\right\}$$

$$= \frac{1}{24} \times [3i^5 - 10i^4 + 9i^3 - 2i^2].$$

---

$$H = \sum_{i=3}^n g(i) = \sum_{i=1}^n g(i) - \sum_{i=1}^2 g(i).$$

Again, there is a mild shortcut here.  Note that $~\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^2 g(i) = 0.$

Therefore,

$$H = \sum_{i=1}^n g(i) \\
= \frac{1}{24} \times \sum_{i=1}^n [3i^5 - 10i^4 + 9i^3 - 2i^2] \\
= \frac{1}{24} \times \\
\left\{ \\
~~\left[\frac{n^6}{2} + \frac{3n^5}{2} + \frac{5n^4}{4} - \frac{n^2}{4}\right] \\
- \left[2n^5 + 5n^4 + \frac{10n^3}{3} - \frac{n}{3}\right] \\
+ \left[\frac{9n^4}{4} + \frac{9n^3}{2} + \frac{9n^2}{4}\right] \\
- \left[\frac{2n^3}{3} + n^2 + \frac{n}{3}\right] \\
\right\}$$

$$= \frac{1}{24} \times \left[\frac{n^6}{2} - \frac{n^5}{2} - \frac{3n^4}{2} + \frac{n^3}{2} + n^2\right].$$